# Understanding Material Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a material navigation drawer, so i read the google doc about it, and I found [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Now, I have a problem. In the `MainActivity` class, the adapter is set like this:

```
// Set the adapter for the list view
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
```

I don't understand which layout is `drawer_list_item`, in fact Android Studio is giving me an error.

Comment: this is the layout of each item you are going to add to navigation drawer, you have to design because I think you are trying to create custom navigation drawer

Comment: actually there is a latest widget `NavigationView` which you can use to create Material Navigation Drawer. I would recommend using this widget instead of handling your own list view.

Comment: You can at least read the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, T[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand Material Navigation Drawer,do simple process.

1)For new application:
Create application with Navigation Drawer template.
So you will get one sample of navigation drawer.

2)With existing application:
Create new activity with Navigation Drawer

[image: Create activity with navigation drawer]

Answer (score 1):

`drawer_list_item` is a layout for single list item. When you are using ArrayAdapter, this layout should contains only `TextView`.

> By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView.

If you don't have such a layout, you can replace `R.layout.drawer_list_item` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlanetTitles));
```